# one button in each section of uiTableView objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a uitableview and in my table I have different section and in each section different rows,I want to add one button in last row of each sections

I used sectionFooter, and here is my code, but I don't know why I have it just in my last section of table and also it's not appear with scroll.

Here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 50;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(footerView == nil) {

    footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

  //  [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //the button should be as big as a table view cell
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 300, 44)];

    //set title, font size and font color
    [button setTitle:@"Report New Time" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //set action of the button
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(removeAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //add the button to the view
    [footerView addSubview:button];
}

//return the view for the footer
return footerView;
}
```

what is wrong here, Would you please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try same code after removing the if condition you have placed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the if statement in your tableView:viewForFooterInSection: method. That's causing only one view to be created.

Answer (score 0):

One UIView has to have only one superview. You have to create footerView for every section.

Comment: Don't store footerView at instance variable, create one for every call of -tableView: viewForFooterInSection:.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the `footerView` for every section, partly by just keeping one `footerView` instance variable, partly by just creating it once. Every time `UITableView` asks you for a footer view for a section and it gets back the same view, that view is moved since it can't stay in all those places at the same time. The solution is to not use a single view.

Use an `NSMutableDictionary` to hold `NSNumber`s with the section number as key and the appropriate footer view as the value. Change the code to work with the section's "slot" in the dictionary instead of a single instance variable.